# Adding an item to a dictionary and calling to a dict with a variable - Python

Tags: python, variables, dictionary

I've got a problem. I would like to call to a dictionary and add an item, but I want to call to it by a variable.

```
if zacetek in predmeti:
    ocena = str(raw_input("Vpisite oceno: "))
    procent = str(raw_input("Vpisite procent: "))
    zacetek[ocena] = procent
```

Zacetek is a string inside a list named predmeti. Dictionaries are named the same as the strings in that list. I basicly check if the input(zacetek) is in those list of strings and then call to a dictionary named like that. But I can't call because it says that zacetek is a string and not an object. How could I get a dictionary like this?

Thank you!

Comment: Need more context. Can you include the definitions / contents of `zacetek` and `predmeti`?

Comment: _"Dictionaries are named the same as the strings..."_ - in python, objects are only named in some sort of context. For instance, if the dictionaries are named at the module level, you could do `globals()[zacetek][ocena] = procent` to get them. So, question is... where are these dicts named?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use the string as a dictionary. Try setting a variable to a dictionary, and setting it's keys.

```
predmeti = [] # strings here
zacetek_dict = {}
zacetek = raw_input('Input: ')

if zacetek in predmeti:
    ocena = str(raw_input("Vpisite oceno: "))
    procent = str(raw_input("Vpisite procent: "))
    zacetek_dict[ocena] = procent
```

Answer (score 0):

Since zacetek is already a string, you can't treat it like a dictionary.

If I'm understanding you correctly, you are trying to create a dictionary. You'll want a new variable for that.  If this is inside a loop, instantiate the new variable outside the loop like this:

```
new_dict = {}
# or
new_dict = dict()
```

Otherwise, if you only need it to have one item in it, you can just set it up as you have:

```
new_dict = {ocena: procent}
```

Comment: ocena is a variable. Why are you setting it as a string?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

`raw_input` already gives you a string. You don't have to attempt to convert to a string (`str(raw_input([prompt]))`, `raw_input([prompt])` is good enough.

Also, `Zacetek` is a string. You can only index keys and values if the **object is a dictionary**. Since, `Predmeti` is a data type (`list` or `dict`), you can append to that, or even convert `Zacetek` to a string and append to that object.

```
predmeti = {zacetek: {}} # Zacetek is a dictionary
predmeti[zacetek][ocena] = procent # Get's the value of zacetek (Which is a 
                                   # dictionary),then adds a key and a 
                                   # value to it.
```